# Python, effect of parentheses on booleans in print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Would you please explain to me why the parentheses affect the output of booleans passed to a print statement?

Example:

```
print(True and False) or (True or False)
#         False       or      True
# Python 2.7 >>> True
# Python 3.6 >>> False
```

But when I use parentheses:

```
print((True and False) or (True or False))
#          False       or      True
# Python 2.7 >>> True
# Python 3.6 >>> True
```

Does the interpreter in Python 3 only see the first part (the one inside the first parentheses)? if so, why it doesn't throw an error for the rest of the line?

Other examples:

```
print(True and True) and (True and False)
#          True      and      False
# Python 2.7 >>> False
# Python 3.6 >>> True

print((True and True) and (True and False))
#          True       and      False
# Python 2.7 >>> False
# Python 3.6 >>> False

print(True and True) and not (False or True)
#         True       and not       True
# Python 2.7 >>> False
# Python 3.6 >>> True

print((True and True) and not (False or True))
#         True        and not       True
# Python 2.7 >>> False
# Python 3.6 >>> False

print(False or True) and not (True and True)
#          True      and not       True
# Python 2.7 >>> False
# Python 3.6 >>> True

print((False or True) and not (True and True))
#          True       and not       True
# Python 2.7 >>> False
# Python 3.6 >>> False
```

**UPDATE FROM ANSWERS AND COMMENTS:**

my question in **BOLD**:

In Python3, print is a function.
`print(True and False)` is `None`, and

`print(True and False) or (True or False)`

is the same as

`None and (True or False)`

which is `False`, as None is false-y in boolean context.

**isn't like telling the interpreter to print something or evaluate other stuff? how can this be a valid syntax?**

**since the first part was evaluated to `None`
then the second evaluation:
`None and (True or False)`
shouldn't print anything unless i run it in the shell.**
for example: running `None and (True or False)` wouldn't print the result to user if it run in a code editor like SublimeText3
(I don't use any extra plugin or package in sublime, only the build function of the program, and it doesn't print anything unless it's passed to a print statement.)

[image: little gif to demonstrate]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python3, `print` is a function. As all functions who don't have a specific return value, it returns `None`.

So, what happens when you execute `print(True and False) or (True or False)` is the following:

`True and False` gets evaluated, which gives `False`.

The function`print()` gets called with `False` as argument.
This `print(False)` first prints "False" to the terminal, then returns the value `None`.

Now,

```
None or (True or False)
```

gets evaluated to True.

If you execute this as part of a script, "False" gets printed, the whole expression gets evaluated to `True`, and as you don't assign this `True` to anything, it is just discarded.

If you execute this in the REPL, "False" gets printed, the whole expression gets evaluated to `False`, and the REPL prints the result of the evaluation, as it would have printed 4 if you had entered 2+2, so you get

```
>>> print(True and False) or (True or False)
False  # <-- from print
True  # <-- from the REPL, result of the evaluation of the whole expression
```

---

There's a little difference if you execute `print(True and False) and (True or False)`. This time, after printing, the expression is

```
None and (True or False)
```

As `None` is falsy in boolean context, Python knows that the result of `and` will be false (without even needing to evaluate the `(True or False)` part), and returns `None`, as it is the first value that allowed it to decide the truthiness of the expression.

If you execute this as part of a script, as before, "False" gets printed, the whole expression gets evaluated to `None`, and as you don't assign this `None` to anything, it is just discarded.

If you execute this in the REPL, "False" gets printed, the whole expression gets evaluated to `None`. As this is the ordinary return value of all functions who return nothing, the REPL doesn't print it unless you explicitely ask it to :

```
>>> print(True and False) and (True or False)
False  # <-- from print, None doesn't get printed
>>> print(print(True and False) and (True or False))
False  # <-- from the inner print
None   # <-- None gets printed by the outer print 
>>>
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand you, when I run `print(True and False)` in Python 3 it gives `False` not `None`, would please explain more.

Comment: It **prints** False, but **returns** None. Try `a = print('Hello')` then `print(a)`, you will see that a is None.

Comment: kindly see my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691955/python-effect-of-parentheses-on-booleans-in-print-statement/49692056?noredirect=1#comment86397216_49692056) to better understand my confusion about this

Comment: Maybe you could update your question by adding what still confuses you, it will be easier to find than in the comments.

Comment: thank you for updating your answer, kindly see the the `gif` picture I added to the question, the interpreter doesn't print unless there is a print statement, or in Python3 a print function, and that's what's expected from it. but still as in your answer when evaluating the first part passed to the print function `print(True and False)` >>> `None` so now we have `None and (True or False)` without print statement/function so that shouldn't show any output on the screen, just like if I run `(True and False) or (True or False)` no output is printed.

Comment: @MuhammadOsta My bad, I had mixed things during the copy-pasting of expressions and outputs. Should be clearer this time!

Answer (score 2):

Print is a statement in Python2 so it doesn't need the parenthesis, while it's a function in Python3 so it does need them.

So Python2 see `print(True and False) or (True or False)` as a single statement, while Python3 sees `print(True and False)` as a valid statement in itself and computes that.

Comment: so why it doesn't throw an error after evaluating `print(True and False)`?

Comment: Because it evaluates that first, then evaluates if the output of it against the rest. i.e. After executing the print instruction, it checks `None and (True or False)` which is a valid logical operation that evaluates to False.

Comment: ok it's a valid logical operation, but why in this case it print the result on the screen? since the first part was evaluated to `None` then the second evaluation `None and (True or False)` shouldn't print anything unless i run it in the shell. for example: running `None and (True or False)` wouldn't print the result to user if it run in a code editor like SublimeText3

Comment: That's because the REPL outputs the result of an operation back to the terminal, to save you having to print everything you run. So running `1 == 2` will print False in the REPL without having to say `print(1 == 2)`. This isn't the case when running a script, in which case you must use print to output values.

Comment: I don't use any extra plugin or package in sublime, only the build function of the program, and it doesn't print anything unless it's passed to a print statement.

Comment: That's expected, because it's being run as a python script. The REPL is designed to be used to testing single statements really which is why it has extra output.

Answer (score 1):

In python 2, `print` is a statement. As a result, everything after the `print` is evaluated as a single expression.

For example,

```
print(True and False) or (True or False)
```

is evaluated like

```
result = (True and False) or (True or False)
print result
```

But in python 3, `print` is a function, and only the expression inside the parenthesis is printed:

```
result = True and False
print(result) or (True or False)
```

This looks weird, but is valid syntax, because `print` is a function. It's essentially equivalent to this:

```
result = True and False
result2 = print(result)
final_result = result2 or (True or False)
```

In short, it's like python 2 adds an additional pair of parentheses around everything after `print`.

Comment: but isn't like telling the interpreter to `print something` or `evaluate other stuff`? how can this be a valid syntax?

Comment: @MuhammadOsta A function call is an expression (i.e. it returns a value), so obviously things like `foo() or bar()` are valid syntax, right? `print` is also a function, so `print(result) or True` is also valid syntax. It's unintuitive because you usually don't use `print` for its return value, but it's valid nonetheless.

Comment: I understand the `print` work as function in Python3, but if I have a function called `myfunction` which `return False` then running: `print myfunction() or (True or False)` gives: `invalid syntax`

Comment: @MuhammadOsta That's only invalid syntax in python 3 because there are no parentheses after the `print`. `print(myfunction() or (True or False))` works, as does `print(myfunction()) or (True or False)`.

Comment: yes, I understand Python 3 need parentheses but when I actually run `print(True and False) or (True or False)` it's not considered invalid syntax, it's like the interpreter is evaluating the whole line not just the first part inside the parentheses.

Comment: @MuhammadOsta There is no python where that throws a syntax error. I don't know what you're doing wrong, but the syntax error is probably on a different line.

Comment: no it doesn't throw a syntax error, I'm actually wondering why it doesn't. I updated the question kindly check it out.